# How do you change the command line options for a default application?

Tags: default-browser

I need to add --no-remote to the default browser so that it does not clash with the other profiles i have running concurrently. This is for the os level default application launch. for example inside of a game there is a link that when you click on it the os tries to launch a new browser session to show the page it refers to.  how can this be done?

Comment: Are you talking about starting the browser manually from the command line, or as when started by some other application (e.g., clicking a link in a PDF, etc.)?

Comment: from another application, ie the default browser command in the os. lanunching the default app chooser only allows selecting the app not adding command lines. I am sure other default app types could need command lines depending on situations.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you're actually trying to achieve in details (what you said in the comments above). Right now it sounds kinda vague and would attract simpler answers which would not be useful to you. Also did you try adding `no-remote` to the `Exec=` line of Firefox's `.desktop` launcher?